# SQLite - Join using Wildcards

Tags: sql, sqlite, join

Strange one... Im attempting to join two tables together using a wildcard. This is usually a straight forward task, yet for some reason the query returns nothing. However, when I comment the table im trying to join on and enable to the same clause within the WHERE clause I get results.

Any thoughts?

```
  SELECT DISTINCT S.column_3
FROM TABLE1 O
INNER JOIN TABLE2 S ON S.column_1 = O.org_id
--Use of the join clause below returns nothing.
INNER JOIN TABLE2 V ON S.column_3 LIKE '%'+V.ven_name+'%'
WHERE
O.org_id = 4
--The clause returns expected values
AND S.column_3 LIKE 'DONINGTON%';

-- Column_3 = Donington Park GP 
-- Ven_Name = Donington
```

Comment: Use `||` for string concatenation.

Comment: Thanks very much Gordon.